# Are there any synonyms for the word high-concept?

Tags: synonyms

Are there any synonyms for the word "high-concept"?

Here is the sentence:"The same goes for some of the high concept scenes in the film – I was often creating a new mix down nearly every single day with new ideas and sounds for him and the picture editors to review and reflect on".

According to dictionary it means "a simple and often striking idea or premise, as of a story or film, that lends itself to easy promotion and marketing" but I couldn't find an appropriate synonym of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Marketable*** and ***commercial*** capture the "lends itself to easy promotion and marketing" aspect of the definition, but without being limited to the domains of film and story telling.

Given that marketable/commercial films and so-called high-concept films (which have striking and salable premises) are pretty much co-extensive at this point, you might get away with using any of these words.

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[climactic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/climactic)*** can be used to refer to the rilevante scendesse of a movie:

> - Acting as a culmination or resolution to a series of events; forming an exciting climax:
>     *the film’s climactic scenes*

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [*showcase*](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=629&bih=412&noj=1&ei=M0KBVsDNEYe_OuScgogE&q=%22the+showcase+scenes+in%22&oq=%22the+showcase+scenes+in%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...3207.8270.0.9057.15.15.0.0.0.0.374.3310.0j8j6j1.15.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..7.8.1682.bojw5LhjKnw) and [*featured*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22the+featured+scenes+in%22&biw=609&bih=400&noj=1&prmd=ivn&ei=XUOBVuqJPMeSasmsubgK&start=10&sa=N&dpr=2)/[*feature*](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=623&bih=409&noj=1&ei=xEGBVuaLK4f1UMujvMAK&q=%22the+feature+scenes+in%22&oq=%22the+feature+scenes+in%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...7988.30498.0.30950.55.55.0.0.0.0.858.14173.0j18j26j8j1j1j1.55.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..28.27.6646.24yK8xn7Y00) *[scenes]*.

> **showcase**:
>
> *n.* A setting, occasion, or medium for exhibiting something or someone especially in an attractive or favorable aspect [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/showcase)
>
> *adj.* Displayed or meriting display as in a showcase [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/showcase)
>
> **feature**:
>
> *adj. n.*
>
> 1. a prominent or conspicuous part or characteristic.
> 2. something offered as a special or main attraction. [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/showcase)